# What happens if you don't dispose HttpContext.Current.Items?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using `HttpContext.Current.Items` to set a tenant based on the logged on user. For this I am using the following code:

```
protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items["_CurrentTenant"] = Tenant.GetCurrent();
}

protected virtual void Application_EndRequest()
{
    var currentTenant = HttpContext.Current.Items["_CurrentTenant"] as Tenant;
    if (currentTenant != null)
        currentTenant.Dispose();
}
```

Since the `HttpContext.Current.Items` only lives in the current request, I would expect it to be destroyed after the request is finished. Also, the `CurrentTenant` object is a fully managed object.

Therefore, is it required to dispose in the `EndRequest`? What happens if you don't do that?

Comment: Why not try it out? Comment out the lines where you're disposing it and try it out

Comment: Of course I did try, but no noticable effect. I'm wondering for example if omitting it could lead to memory leaks. Also, does it make sense if the Tenant object is not disposable anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to say with your last sentence "Also, does it make sense if the Tenant object is not disposable anyway" is the Tenant object of type IDisposable or not?

Comment: The container might get destroyed, but if you extract a reference to an item and store it elsewhere, that item remains alive for as long as you keep the reference to it.

Comment: if it's inheriting from IDisposable it should be disposed when it's out of scope

Comment: Rule of thumb: If an Object inherits from IDisposable, always dispose of it when it's out of scope. If not, let the GC take care of it

Comment: The Tenant Object does not inherit from iDisposable. So in that case can I assume the GC takes care of it and you don't need to dispose it (even though it lives in HttpContext.Current.Items)?

Comment: You might consider looking at the [DisposeOnPipelineCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.disposeonpipelinecompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, which tells ASP.NET to dispose an item when the request is done.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, is it required to dispose in the EndRequest?

Only you can know, whether disposing the object at the end of the request is something you want. Make sure it gets disposed when it's no longer used. If that's at the end of the request, then that might be a good spot.

> What happens if you don't do that?

The `.Dispose()` method won't be called. What that means for your specific class is something only you can say. The normal pattern would call `.Dispose()` in the finalizer, but until then, it can take a while. What happens in that time is completely dependent on why it was marked as `IDisposible` in the first place. Maybe files do not get closed, connections might stay open, handles might not be returned... only you can know if it's your class.

Comment: The Tenant Object does not inherit from iDisposable. So in that case can I assume the GC takes care of it and you don't need to dispose it (even though it lives in HttpContext.Current.Items)?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your question. If it does not implement IDisposible, it *cannot* be disposed. Do you maybe mean "garbage collected"? Yes that happens automatically, to every object when the last reference to it goes out of scope.

Comment: @MartindeRuiter yes you only need to do dispose objects which have IDisposable and objects which that interface do so because they might be holding on to expensive resources such as database connections.

Comment: I'm basically worried that if you only set HttpContext.Current.Items in the BeginRequest and don't remove, dispose or let it garbage collected anywhere (e.g. EndRequest), it would lead to memory leaks. Or does the GC take care of it if you use completely managed code (which my Tenant object is)?